# Python 3 append to an empty list after a for loop - I get an empty file (updated/edited question)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

I'm having a bit of a trouble with something which is supposed to be fairly simple.
I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape emails from a dataframe filled with urls.
I want to save all the scraped emails to a dataframe and save it as a csv. Problem is that I only get an empty csv file after I appended to a list with a for loop. See the attached code.
I also added a table with two exapmle urls.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("url.xlsx") # use the table attached 
all_urls = [x for x in df['URL']]

for url in all_urls:

    # regex pattern
    pattern = r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+"

    # initialize the session
    session = HTMLSession()

    # send the get request
    response = session.get(url)

    # simulate JS running code
    response.html.render()

    # get body element
    body = response.html.find("body")[0]

    # extract emails
    emails = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", body.text)

    mail_list = []
    for index, email in enumerate(emails):
        mail_list.append(email)
        #print(index, email)

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(mail_list, columns=["Emails"])
    df2.to_csv('Emails.csv', index=False)
```

The url excel file looks like this (these are actual urls for example purposes) -

| URL |
| --- |
| https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0165176516303640 |
| https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128021170000023 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes to your code.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("url.xlsx") # use the table attached 
all_urls = [x for x in df['URL']]
mail_list = []

for url in all_urls:

    # regex pattern
    pattern = r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+"

    # initialize the session
    session = HTMLSession()

    # send the get request
    response = session.get(url)

    # simulate JS running code
    response.html.render()

    # get body element
    body = response.html.find("body")[0]

    # extract emails
    emails = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", body.text)

    
    for index, email in enumerate(emails):
        mail_list.append(email)
        #print(index, email)

df2 = pd.Dataframe(mail_list, columns=["Emails"])
df2.to_csv('Emails.csv', index=False)
```